# Restore pre-selected values in Chosen Select

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

In the fiddle attached, I have two options pre-filled "Denmark" and "France", when the chosen select loads. If I select more values in the select box and click the clear button, I would like to restore the chosen select with the same pre-filled values "Denmark" and "France".

I would like to change this code to prefill selected values.

```
$("#Clear").click(function () {
    $('.chosen-select option').prop('selected', false).trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsm0615g/1/)

UPDATE:
It would be really good if there is a way such that it doesn't matter which options are pre-filled, but they should be restored, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to create an array of pre-selected option's value. Then you can use a `forEach` loop with this array to change the value of `selected` and get the initial state before trigger update.

```
$("#countries").chosen();

let preselected = [];

$('[selected]').each((i, node) =>{
  preselected.push($(node).attr('value'));
});

$("#Clear").click(function () {
    $('.chosen-select option').prop('selected', false);

    preselected.forEach(pre => {
      $(".chosen-select option[value='" + pre + "']")
      .attr('selected', 'selected')
      .trigger('chosen:updated');
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsm0615g/6/)

As you can see [here](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html) there's nothing in the plugin you can use to achieve this, it seems you have to do it by changing your DOM and trigger update. I would use the code from luckyape answer and mine, mixing it.

Comment: is there a way to make it such that, it doesn't matter what options are prefilled, but they should be  restored, if any?

Comment: Well you could loop when onload to know whichs elements are selected and retrieve it.

Comment: @Jake The previous snippet frezeed the page when you pressed Clear button, trigering the event inside the loop solves it.

Answer (score 6):

Give this a go

```
$("#countries").chosen();

$("#Clear").click(function () {
    $('.chosen-select option').prop('selected', false);
    $('.chosen-select').val(['Denmark', 'France']).trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y5cnd018/

Comment: This works as well, but is there a way to make it such that, it doesn't matter what options are prefilled, but they should be restored, if any? Jose gave a good solution above, but wondering if chosen has something that already does this, like you provided.